# Test Coverage Stuck at 70%

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have this class and test class and I'm stucke with 70% code coverage.

```
public with sharing class GoodStandingAsOfController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}

    public GoodStandingAsOfController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

            this.controller = controller;
            this.a = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        }
        private Account a;
        public List<Account> searchResults {get;set;}

        public date AsOfDate {
            get {
                if (AsOfDate == null) 
                    AsOfDate =  system.today();//'2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z'  ; 
                return AsOfDate;   
            }
            set;    
        }


        public String StateText {get;set;}

        public String AccountStatusText {
            get {
                if(AccountStatusText == null)
                    AccountStatusText = 'All';
                return AccountStatusText;
            }
            set;
        }
        //set default GoodStandingStatusText
        public String GoodStandingStatusText {
            get {
                if(GoodStandingStatusText == null)
                    GoodStandingStatusText = 'Compliant';
                return GoodStandingStatusText;
            }
            set;
        }

        // Set ReasonText
        public String ReasonText {
            get {
                if (ReasonText == null) 
                    ReasonText = 'usaa';
                return ReasonText;   
            }
            set;
        }


        public pagereference ProcessRecords(){
            list <Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c>  GSRU = new list <Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c>();

            List<Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c> ReportDelete = [select id from Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c where OwnerID = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 50000];
            delete ReportDelete;
            //query Active or Inactive accounts.
            string qryActiveOrInactive = 'SELECT Partner_ID__c, Name, BillingCity, BillingState, Status__c, '+
                'Good_Standing_Status__c , (select Good_Standing_Status_New__c , Change_Date__c, Out_Of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c '+
                ' from Good_Standing_Status_History__r '+ 
                'where Change_Date__c < ' +
                String.ValueOf(AsOfDate) +'T00:00:00.000Z'+ 
                ' and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = \''+GoodStandingStatusText+'\' '+

                ' ORDER BY Change_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1) '+
                ' from Account '+
                ' where BillingState = \''+StateText+'\' '+
                ' AND Type = \'U.S. Affiliate\' '+
                ' AND Status__c = \''+AccountStatusText+'\' '+
                ' and  id in (select account__c '+
                '            from Good_Standing_Status_History__c '+ 
                'where Change_Date__c < ' +
                String.ValueOf(AsOfDate) +'T00:00:00.000Z'+
                '          and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = \''+GoodStandingStatusText+'\' '+
                '        ) ';

            string qryAllActiveInactive = 'SELECT Partner_ID__c, Name, BillingCity, BillingState, Status__c, '+
                'Good_Standing_Status__c , (select Good_Standing_Status_New__c , Change_Date__c, Out_Of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c '+
                ' from Good_Standing_Status_History__r '+ 
                'where Change_Date__c < ' +
                String.ValueOf(AsOfDate) +'T00:00:00.000Z'+ 
                ' and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = \''+GoodStandingStatusText+'\' '+
                ' ORDER BY Change_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1) '+
                ' from Account '+
                ' where BillingState = \''+StateText+'\' '+
                ' AND Status__c LIKE  \'%%\' '+
                ' AND Type = \'U.S. Affiliate\' '+
                ' and  id in (select account__c '+
                '            from Good_Standing_Status_History__c '+ 
                'where Change_Date__c < ' +
                String.ValueOf(AsOfDate) +'T00:00:00.000Z'+
                '          and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = \''+GoodStandingStatusText+'\' '+
                '        ) ';
            //Reset Qry string
            string qry = ''; 
            if(AccountStatusText == 'All') {qry = qryAllActiveInactive;} else { qry=qryActiveOrInactive;}

            List <Account> GSResults = Database.Query(qry);

            List<Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c> toInsertGood_Standing_AsOf_Report = new List<Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c>();
            for (Account upd : GSResults){

                Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c GSR = new Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c();
                for(Good_Standing_Status_History__c updc:upd.Good_Standing_Status_History__r){
                    gsr.AccountName__c = upd.name;
                    gsr.Partner_ID__c = upd.Partner_ID__c;
                    gsr.City__c = upd.BillingCity;
                    gsr.State__c = upd.BillingState;
                    gsr.AsOfDate__c = updc.Change_Date__c;
                    gsr.Good_Standing_Status__c = updc.Good_Standing_Status_New__c;
                    gsr.Reason__c = updc.Out_of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c;
                    gsr.Account_Status__c = upd.Status__c;
                    gsr.Requested_Account_Status__c = AccountStatusText;
                    gsr.Requested_AsOfDate__c = String.ValueOf(AsOfDate);
                    gsr.Requested_GS_Status__c = GoodStandingStatusText;
                }
                toInsertGood_Standing_AsOf_Report.add(gsr);

            }
            insert toInsertGood_Standing_AsOf_Report;

            if (searchResults == null) {
                searchResults = new List<Account>(); // init the list if it is null
            } else {
                searchResults.clear(); // clear out the current results if they exist
            }
            searchResults = Database.query(qry);
            return null;
        } 

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class GoodStandingAsOfControllerTest{

    @isTest
    static public void rollUpOverride(){

     PageReference tpageRef = Page.GoodStandingReport;
     Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

Account accList = new Account();
acclist.Name ='Test Account';
acclist.Partner_Id__c=' 1514-8671';
acclist.BillingState='GA';
acclist.BillingCity='Americus';
acclist.Type='U.S. Affiliate';
acclist.BillingCity='Oakland';
acclist.Out_of_Good_Standing_Reason_Text__c ='Missing Sample';
acclist.Status__c ='Active';
insert accList;


ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', accList.Id);

GoodStandingAsOfController controller = new GoodStandingAsOfController (new ApexPages.StandardController(acclist));
controller.StateText = 'NY';
//controller.Status = 'Active';
//controller.Type = 'U.S. Affiliate';


Good_Standing_Status_History__c upd = new Good_Standing_Status_History__c ();
upd.Account__c = acclist.id;
upd.Change_Date__c = System.today();
upd.Good_Standing_Status_New__c = 'Complaint';
upd.Out_Of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c   = 'Missing Sample';
insert upd;



controller.ProcessRecords();


  }

}
```

It doesn't cover the following lines of code. What am I missing?

```
   Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c GSR = new Good_Standing_AsOf_Report__c();
        for(Good_Standing_Status_History__c updc:upd.Good_Standing_Status_History__r){
            gsr.AccountName__c = upd.name;
            gsr.Partner_ID__c = upd.Partner_ID__c;
            gsr.City__c = upd.BillingCity;
            gsr.State__c = upd.BillingState;
            gsr.AsOfDate__c = updc.Change_Date__c;
            gsr.Good_Standing_Status__c = updc.Good_Standing_Status_New__c;
            gsr.Reason__c = updc.Out_of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c;
            gsr.Account_Status__c = upd.Status__c;
            gsr.Requested_Account_Status__c = AccountStatusText;
            gsr.Requested_AsOfDate__c = String.ValueOf(AsOfDate);
            gsr.Requested_GS_Status__c = GoodStandingStatusText;
        }
        toInsertGood_Standing_AsOf_Report.add(gsr);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is getting filtered based on `Change_Date__c` of `Good_Standing_Status_History__r` and other attributes of the Account.

You need to create those records which will satisfy the query condition.

```
Account accList = new Account(Name ='acct', Partner_Id__c='0600-6181', BillingState='NY', Type='U.S. Affiliate');
insert accList;

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', accList.Id);


GoodStandingAsOfController controller = new GoodStandingAsOfController (new ApexPages.StandardController(acclist));
controller.StateText = 'NY';

Good_Standing_Status_History__c upd = new Good_Standing_Status_History__c ();
upd.Account__c = acclist.id;
upd.Change_Date__c = System.today().addDays(-1);
insert upd;
```

Also, follow [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) to put proper assert, runAs(user) etc. which are missing in test class.

Comment: Hi sorry, for late reply, where should i add those records? is it in account? thanks!

Comment: Yes, in the account, idea is if you need to cover and test the scenario you have to prepare the records accordingly.

Comment: Hi Santanu, I have added Account accList = new Account(Name ='acct', Partner_Id__c='0600-6181', BillingState='NY', Type='U.S. Affiliate', BillingCity='Oakland', Out_of_Good_Standing_Reason_Text__c ='Missing Sample', Status__c ='Active');
insert accList; this to account still it is still 70%.. Am I missing something?

Comment: this is the result of the database QRY =18:14:07:175 USER_DEBUG [118]|DEBUG|qrytest:SELECT Partner_ID__c, Name, BillingCity, BillingState, Status__c, Good_Standing_Status__c , (select Good_Standing_Status_New__c , Change_Date__c, Out_Of_Good_Standing_Reason_New__c  from Good_Standing_Status_History__r where Change_Date__c < 2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = 'Compliant'  ORDER BY Change_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: from Account  where BillingState = 'NY'  AND Status__c LIKE  '%%'  AND Type = 'U.S. Affiliate'  and  id in (select account__c             from Good_Standing_Status_History__c where Change_Date__c < 2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z          and Good_Standing_Status_New__c = 'Compliant'         )

Comment: I edited the Test class above still stuck at 70%